# How to place Div below my iFrame video

Tags: html, css, video, iframe

I currently have a iframe video and sitting on top of this are 4 clickable images. Below this, I want to have a contact Me page, however, the problem I am facing is How to get my Contact Me div blow the iframe video. Can someone Help me sort this problem out? Currently, on my codepen, you will see that i have applied a linear gradriend which is where the video is to be placed, and even though I have a Contact Me div in place, it is not placed in the top left hand corner, behind the iframe video, and I want it to be below the div, totally separated from it.

You can see my code on my Codepen, [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEYwdE)

and this is what i currently have :
[image]

```
.
```

As you can see from the screen shot, this is the front page, but the "contact me" div is placed behind the video, in the top corner... can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have too many elements with absolute positioning. You don't need all of that.
To position an element absolutely relative to its parent element all you have to do is add **position: relative** to the **parent** and **position: absolute** to the **child**.

And because you're positioning everything absolutely, elements are losing their height and it's why your contact div is moving to the top because the flow of the page is broken, and therefore, your contact div doesn't really see elements above it. Plus, you have **color: white** on the body and that applies to everything on your page including the contact div. change it and you'll find your contact on top of your header.

If you need more info I'm happy to help.

Comment: thank you for replying. So then which ones should i change in order to fix this problem? because i am not too sure which ones to leave and which ones to change, thank you for helping! I have changed the colour to blue or something to make it easier to see, but still do not know where to position what

Comment: you can do something like this. I stripped the html styles and re-did almost everything related to your question. I rearranged some of the html too. check it out here. [link](http://codepen.io/Hadeel90/pen/YWBXYW?editors=1100)

Comment: my god did you fix it?! thank you so very very much! i thought you had changed it, now it looks like there is some structure ahah!

Comment: You're welcome. Next time try to have version control (Git) it'll help you fix things like this. Going back a few steps helps almost every time.

Answer (score 0):

Your contact header is there. It is in the top left corner, but it is white (at least that is what I see on the code link)Give the `<h1>` a style color to help make it stand out, `<h1 style="color:blue;">`  etc. Also move the div to above the image in your code. That should also help.

Comment: I changed it, which is fine, but I want the Contact Me div to be below the entire video so i can have a contact form totally separated from the video, in a section below